# Looking for stdckdint.h in the gcc 11.2 collection

Tags: gcc, c23

I'm trying to find a copy of stdckdint.h, which I assume should be in the gcc 11.2 collection, but a search fails to locate it in the downloaded source tarball.

Is it not public yet, or do I have to unpack/build something to get the include files?

Comment: `Is it not public yet` How do you know it "is" there at all?

Comment: Is not 11.2 meant to contain the c23 proposals?

Comment: I do not know, how do you know? It's rather, you assume something is not there, unless proven, not otherwise. Anyway, gcc11 was released in 2021. It would be impractical to implement "proposal"s from C2x so early.

Comment: Fair enough.  Where would you suggest I look instead?

Comment: gcc implements builtins that provide the same feature, you'd just have to create macros that change the argument order

Comment: @Ian, GCC 11 contained _some_ C2x features (see the [gcc-11](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/changes.html#c), [gcc-10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html#c), and [gcc-9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html#c) release notes for details), but as noted it's unreasonable to expect a compiler released in 2021 to have complete support for a standard that was only finished in 2023 and still isn't published in 2024.

Answer (score 4):

Gcc11 does not provide `stdckdint.h`. The documentation of gcc does not mentions it, neither in release notes nor in C standard support page. As the documentation states, C2x support in GCC is incomplete and experimental. The release notes for gcc11 lists implemented C2x features.

In the meantime, you can use my implementation available from https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/ckd/-/tree/master .

Comment: Some progress? https://github.com/a4lg/gcc/commit/8441841a1b985d68245954af1ff023db121b0635

Comment: There's this: https://www.gnu.org/software//gnulib/manual/html_node/stdckdint_002eh.html. But still not available anywhere, it would seem.